# Error en juntar métodos $_POST y $_GET en comprobación switch case

Tags: php

Cuando existe datos por método `post` siempre va existir el dato `Pending` y si no existe datos por método `post` debe dejar pasar a los datos por metodo `get` por lo tanto si en la url existe el dato `cancel` o si no existe pasara aún mensaje por defaul `Procees`.

```
    if (empty($_POST['payment_status'])) || if (empty($_GET['payment_status'])) $_GET['payment_status'] = 'Procees';
    switch ($_POST['payment_status'] OR $_GET['payment_status'])) {
        case 'cancel':
            # code...
            break;
        case 'Procees':
            # code...
            break;
        case 'Pending':
            # code...
            break;
    }
```

Pero no me funciona me imprime el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '||' (T_BOOLEAN_OR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\dataget.php on line 9

Ya probé usando `&&, ||, OR` pero me muestra el mismo mensaje de error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos a comprobar si en la URL existe valor y si no existe le asignamos un valor por `default` al método `$_GET[]`, de la siguiente manera:

```
if(empty($_GET['cancel'])) $_GET['cancel'] = 'Procees';
```

De la misma forma en el método `$_POST[]` en este caso le asigno un valor vació.

```
if(empty($_POST['payment_status'])) $_POST['payment_status'] = '';
```

Ahora vamos asignar a dos variables distintas, los datos que contiene el método `$_POST[]` y el método `$_GET[]`.

```
$data1 = $_GET['cancel'];
$data2 = $_POST['payment_status'];
```

Ahora esa información la convertiremos en un `Array`

```
$array1 = array($data1);
$array2 = array($data2);
```

Y mediante la función [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php) vamos a combinar ambos `Array`, de la siguiente manera:

```
$resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Mediante el uso de un [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) vamos enviar toda la información al `switch`.

```
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 'Cancel':
            echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Cancel';
            break;
        case 'Procees':
            echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Procees';
            break;
        case 'Pending':
            echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Pending';
            break;
    }
}
```

Otra segunda alternativa es usar la función [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)

```
array_map(function ($id) {
    switch ($id) {
        case 'Cancel':
            echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Cancel';
            break;
        case 'Procees':
            echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Procees';
            break;
        case 'Pending':
            echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Pending';
            break;
    }
}, $resultado);
```

---

Otra alternativa más sencilla es declarar variables en `NULL` y asignarles valor cuando existan datos en los métodos `$_GET` o métodos `$_POST`.

```
//Declarar variable
$data1 = NULL;
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    if(empty($_GET['cancel'])) $_GET['cancel'] = '';
    $data1 = $_GET['cancel'];
}
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['payment_status'])) $_POST['payment_status'] = '';
    $data1 = $_POST['payment_status'];
}
switch ($data1) {
    case 'Pending':
        echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Pending';
        break;
    case 'Completed':
        echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Completed';
        break;
    case 'Canceled':
        echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Cancel';
        break;

    default:
        echo 'Ejecutar las condiciones para Procees';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Gracias funciona perfectamente :)

Comment: @gPH Me alegra que te haya servido :) Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene demasiados errores:

1. Dentro del condicional de la linea 1 estás colocando otro IF
   dentro de forma incorrecta.
2. No estas cerrando bien los corchetes.
3. No estas cerrando los paréntesis bien.
4. Un switch no se usa de esa forma, ya que estas haciendo una
   condiciones dentro de el.

Este código es mi mejor recomendación.

```
<?php
    $p= ((!$_POST['payment_status'] || !$_GET['payment_status']) ? 'Procees':'none');
    switch($p)
        {
        case 'cancel':
            echo "1";
            break;
        case 'Procees':
            echo "2";
            break;
        case 'Pending':
            echo "3";
            break;
        default:
            echo "4";
            break;
        }
?>
```

Te aconsejaría continuar tu aprendizaje en programación y fijarte bien en todos los detalles. Y continuar practicando.

Comment: Amigo su código no funciona, el mensaje `echo 'Error...';` nunca deberá aparecer porque si no llega existir datos tanto en post o get debe pasar al mensaje por defecto que se le ha proporcionado que es el `Process`

Comment: El codigo funciona sin errores, la condicion si varia un poco a su gusto funcionara, tampoco vamos a ofrecerle la solucion a su problema al 100%, debe colocar de su parte.

Comment: de hecho @moneyBox si el OP ya colocó su código y explica lo que ha hecho y lo que intenta obtener si es tu deber dar la respuesta a la pregunta

Comment: @gPH Cierta parte tiene razón **moneyBoox** debe seguir mejorando, pero tambien es cierto que todas estás preguntas con estos errores no solo ayuda al actor de la pregunta sino a muchos lectores esta es la funcionalidad del foro.

Comment: Has preguntado por ese error y @gPH te ha respondido, te fallaba la sentencia if después del OR.

Comment: @IniDesing.com la intención de mi comentario fue reafirmar eso precisamente para que quien respondió mejore y corrija la respuesta para ayudar al OP

Comment: @Tiberius La respuesta no soluciona el problema, si te das cuenta en la pregunta si no existen datos el `switch` debe imprimir valores que va a pasar por un valor por `defaul` en este caso le quiere asignar a `$_GET`, pero en cambio en el código de la respuesta ira directo al mensaje de `echo 'Error...';`

Comment: @alfap Me equivoque en enlazar el comentario :) totalmente de acuerdo.

Comment: corregido... Pero la pregunta estaba dirigida al condicional mal formado el cual resolvi, ya lo adicional fue extra y no viene dentro de la pregunta.

Comment: @moneyBox Su variable `$p= (($_POST['payment_status'] || $_GET['payment_status']) ? 'Process':'none');` imprime error `Notice: Undefined index: payment_status` da paso al mensaje por defaul pero imprime errores, seguiré buscando en la web

Comment: jajajajajaja... en serio usted solo hace copy paste ?, es solo una errata que puedes solucionar, pon un poquito de tu parte.

Comment: @moneyBox Si lo he intentado usando varias formas tanto en el uso de `&&, ||, OR` como otros si supieras tanto código comentado que tengo, debería ser fácil para ti ya que te expresas con gran profesionalismo en este código de tercer nivel, pero tu código genera errores, es como si estuviera trabajando con mi código que sentido tiene su respuesta entonces

Comment: @moneyBox Observe la respuesta de **IniDesing.com** dos ejemplos por falta de uno, por lo menos una respuesta sin errores hubiera estado bien.

Answer (score 1):

Existe otro método de comprobar el envío de datos por PHP. Se trata de $_REQUEST. http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php

Podrías cambiar tu switch por:

```
switch ($_REQUEST('payment_status')) {
```

Y con ello no necesitarías el ||  que intentas poner en el switch

Otra opcion que puedes utilizar es mirar primero la variable $_SERVER, y buscar que accion se esta enviando:

```
$accion = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Este indice de variable te puede devolver, entre otros, GET y POST. Con ello ya sabes en que accion estas, y podrias analizar el valor en una u otra variable.

NOTA: el uso de ambos métodos de comprobación en una misma no es muy correcto, de hecho tiene poco sentido.  Cada método hace referencia a una acción. Post es para creación y Get es para lectura. No tendría mucho sentido que compruebes ambas cosas, a no ser que estés mezclando dichas acciones. Te recomiendo que empieces a ver información sobre el modelo  MVC, y empieces a aplicarlo en tus apps.

Comment: Es buena alternativa me gustaría que me aclararas un poca para ver si me conviene su uso, estoy usando el método de pago de paypal entonces paypal retorna algunas cosas, como el estado en el que se encuentra el pedido es decir `Pending` los otros datos no retorna toca asignarlas de manera manual para asé ejecutar cada acción, por ejemplo si cancela y no paga payapal no devuelve nada, por eso es la idea del metodo GET ya que yo puedo agregar un parámetro por medio de la url de retorno.

Comment: En ese caso parece que pueda ser util. Te he ampliado la respuesta un poco, porque tambien puedes analizar primero que accion esta llegando con $_SERVER, y asi en funcion de una u otra puedes buscar el valor de la variable que te interese. Yo utilizaria $_REQUEST y te quitas de problemas.